# Cosine distance computation between two arrays - Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I want to apply a function `fn`, which is essentially `cosine distance` computation on two large numpy arrays of shapes (10000, 100) and (5000, 100) row-wise, i.e. i calculate a value for each combination of rows in these arrays.

My implementation :

```
import math
def fn(v1,v2):
    sumxx, sumxy, sumyy = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        x = v1[i]; y = v2[i]
        sumxx += x*x
        sumyy += y*y
        sumxy += x*y
    return sumxy/math.sqrt(sumxx*sumyy)
val = []
for i in range(array1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(array2.shape[0]):
        val.append(fn(array1[i, :], array2[j, :]))
```

The function is very fast and takes only few ms:

```
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 1.24 ms
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: `fn` computes cosine similarity between two vectors. i updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** We could simply use [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) with its `cosine` distance functionality -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

val_out = 1 - cdist(array1, array2, 'cosine')
```

**Approach #2 :** Another approach using [`matrix-multiplication`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
def cosine_vectorized(array1, array2):
    sumyy = (array2**2).sum(1)
    sumxx = (array1**2).sum(1, keepdims=1)
    sumxy = array1.dot(array2.T)
    return (sumxy/np.sqrt(sumxx))/np.sqrt(sumyy)
```

**Approach #3 :** Using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to compute the self squared summations for another one -

```
def cosine_vectorized_v2(array1, array2):
    sumyy = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',array2,array2)
    sumxx = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',array1,array1)[:,None]
    sumxy = array1.dot(array2.T)
    return (sumxy/np.sqrt(sumxx))/np.sqrt(sumyy)
```

**Approach #4 :** Bringing in [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) to offload the `square-root` computations for another method -

```
import numexpr as ne

def cosine_vectorized_v3(array1, array2):
    sumyy = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',array2,array2)
    sumxx = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',array1,array1)[:,None]
    sumxy = array1.dot(array2.T)
    sqrt_sumxx = ne.evaluate('sqrt(sumxx)')
    sqrt_sumyy = ne.evaluate('sqrt(sumyy)')
    return ne.evaluate('(sumxy/sqrt_sumxx)/sqrt_sumyy')
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
# Using same sizes as stated in the question
In [185]: array1 = np.random.rand(10000,100)
     ...: array2 = np.random.rand(5000,100)
     ...: 

In [194]: %timeit 1 - cdist(array1, array2, 'cosine')
1 loops, best of 3: 366 ms per loop

In [195]: %timeit cosine_vectorized(array1, array2)
1 loops, best of 3: 287 ms per loop

In [196]: %timeit cosine_vectorized_v2(array1, array2)
1 loops, best of 3: 283 ms per loop

In [197]: %timeit cosine_vectorized_v3(array1, array2)
1 loops, best of 3: 217 ms per loop
```

Comment: It appears that `cdist` already has 1 subtraction done. Thus there's no need to do it again.